# CollectionView didSelectItem does not respond. Why?

Tags: ios, swift, delegation

first of all, i did set the delegates. every other protocol is working with collection views. 
I tested it with the sizeFotItem function. and that worked just fine. But how come that cellForItem function does not respond at all?

Anyone know why?

here is my code;

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.collectionView.delegate = self
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self
    let flow = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    layoutSettings(flow)
    playButtonPressed(self)
}
```

And this is in my extension of my viewController;

```
    extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 9
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionCell
            print(menu.menuArray[indexPath.row])
            cell.cellText.text = menu.menuArray[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }


        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            print("Do something")
        }
    }
```

The funny part is.. I have almost the same code in an other project, and every is working fine. 
Only difference is that the project has an collectionView INSIDE a TableView.

Hopefully one of you find an obvious reason why this is not working. I'm gladly to know why :)

thanks.

PS. Is it normal that the editor doesn't recognize the "extension ViewController" part as code?

Comment: I forgot to say, all user interactions are enabled. if i make the collectionView scrollable, it works just fine.

Comment: `didSelectItem` doesn't response(than what title of your question say) or `cellForItemAt` (then what inside your question)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I just want a response if i touch an collectionViewItem. In this case, if i touch an item. He needs to response by printing "do something"

Comment: You asked in your question *But how come that cellForItem function does not respond at all?* Did you mean `didSelectItemAt`?

Comment: Your extensions definition seems a bit odd, because you are adding extension to  ViewController class not to a specific one. I would suggest you add the extension to the viewController that is the delegate of your Collection View

Comment: yes, sorry i meant didSelectItemAt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by just deleting the CollectionViewCell and making a new one.

I still don't know what was wrong with my previous collectionViewCell, because every protocol was working just fine except for didSelectItemAt..

If anybody had a familiar problem and knows what was going on, I'm still happy to hear what was going on ;)

Comment: are you using storyboard?

Comment: Yes, i use storyboard.

Comment: Maybe there was conflict on the storyboard file

Comment: Probably, i din't see any. and some of my colleagues din't see the problem either. But perhaps something was wrong indeed.

Comment: Did you face merge conflicts on it's storyboard file?

Comment: I'm pretty sure i did not see any conflicts at all.